# Retrieving values from Jquery to a controller in cakephp

Tags: jquery, cakephp

I'm having problem using cakephp with jquery...

my problem is that am not able to get the values posted from jquery to
a controller in php...

my controller file is simple and is given below...

## users_controller.php

```
<?php 

class UsersController extends AppController

{
       var $name = "Users";
       var $uses = null;           //if no DB connection is reuired……….



       function index()
       {

       }

       function login()
       {
                       print_r($this->params['form']);
                       echo "<br/>";
                       echo "<br/>";
                       echo "<br/>";
                       print_r($_REQUEST);
                       echo "<br/>";
                       echo "<br/>";
                       echo "<br/>";
                       print_r($_POST['username']);
                       echo "<br/>";
                       echo "<br/>";
                       echo "<br/>";
                       echo $_POST['data'];
                       echo "<br/>";
                       echo "<br/>";
                       echo "<br/>";
                       print_r($this->data);
                       echo "<br/>";
                       echo "<br/>";
                       echo "<br/>";

         }

}

?>
```

===========================

-> what am doing in this controller is just trying to output the value
posted from jquery,But none

of them seems to work....

->my view files for login is given below

## login.ctp

```
<html>
<head>
<?=$html->css('general');?>
<?=$javascript->link('jquery'); ?>
<?=$javascript->link('jquery.form'); ?>
<?=$javascript->link('LoginValidation'); ?>
</head>
<body>
<h1 align="center"><u>Login Page</u></h1>
<form method="post" action="" id="customForm" name="customForm">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="10">
<tr><td>User Name :</td><td><input id="username" name="username"
type="text" /></td><td><span id="usernameInfo"></span></td></tr>
<tr><td>Password :</td><td><input id="password" name="password"
type="password" /></td><td><span id="passwordInfo"></span>
</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2" align="right"><input id="submit" name="submit"
type="submit" value="Log In" /></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

=============================

->the login view is just a simple one which uses plain php coding...i
havent used any helpers,
  sorry for that.....but am comfortable using this....

->finally my javascript code LoginValidation.js where the view
specific validation is given below

## LoginValidation.js

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function(){

//global vars
var form = $("#customForm");
var username = $("#username");
var password = $("#password");
var usernameInfo = $("#usernameInfo");
var passwordInfo = $("#passwordInfo");
var site_url = "http://localhost/jeffery/cake_jquery/";
//http://localhost/jeffery/cake_jquery/users/login  var str = $
("form").serialize();

//On blur
username.blur(validateUserName);
password.blur(validatePassword);

//On key press
username.keyup(validateUserName);
password.keyup(validatePassword);

//On Submitting
form.submit(function(){
       if(validateUserName()  &  validatePassword() )
               {

                       $.ajax({
                                       type: "POST",
                                       url: "http://localhost/jeffery/cake_jquery/users/login",
                                       data: "username="+ username.val() + "password=" + password.val(),
                                       success: function(){
                                               form.hide();
                                               $('div.success').fadeIn();
                                       }
                               });
                               return false;
               }
               return false;

});



//validation functions
function validateUserName(){
               //if it's NOT valid
               if(username.val() == ""){
                       username.addClass("error");
                       usernameInfo.addClass("error");
                       usernameInfo.text("User Name is required !!!");
                       return false;
               }
               else
               {
                       username.removeClass();
                       usernameInfo.removeClass();
                       usernameInfo.text("");
                       return true;
               }

}

function validatePassword(){

               //it's NOT valid
               if(password.val() == ""){
                       password.addClass("error");
                       passwordInfo.addClass("error");
                       passwordInfo.text("Password is required !!!");
                       return false;
               }
               //it's valid
               else
               {
                       password.removeClass();
                       passwordInfo.removeClass();
                       passwordInfo.text("");
                       return true;
               }
       }


});             //      end of $(document).ready(function()
```

============================================

=> so what i intend to do here is use a login form, validate it and
submit it via ajax, so that page is not refreshed......

=>and am just trying to view the submitted data via ajax in the login
controller just to make sure

that the controller is receiving the value...

=> The problem is I'm not getting the values to be viewed.

Answer (score 0):

In your ajax code there is

```
data: "username="+ username.val() + "password=" + password.val()
```

You are missing the '&', should be:

```
data: "username="+ username.val() + "&password=" + password.val()
```

Comment: Thanz for the reply Daniel.....


ya i did what u told but still no go....its not showing any data.......

but if i submit the page i gets the data ,But i need these data without submitting and so am using

this jquery.................

but with cakephp this stuff isnt going well.............

However if i used the same code in normal php coding, its working perfectly fine...

cuz there am able to get the values to a php page using $_POST[]; method....

The problem is when using cakephp frame work ....

Is there something missing or am using a wrong method to get the data???

HELP